# How to display memory zones content on IDA Pro?

Tags: tools, ida

This is a very naive question about IDA Pro. Once the IDA debugger started, I would like to be able to type a memory address (or a memory zone) and look easily at the content of it (in various format). With `gdb` you would do `print /x *0x80456ef` or, if you want a wider zone, `x /6x 0x80456ef`.

So, what is the best way to display the memory content from the IDA debugger ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [IDAPython](http://code.google.com/p/idapython/) ([documentation](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/)) you can do something like this to print a byte/word/double word:

```
Dword(0x80456ef)
Word(0x80456ef)
Byte(0x80456ef)
```

Or, to print an arbitrary number of bytes:

```
for b in GetManyBytes(0x40138E, 10):
    print "%X" % ord(b)
```

If running in the debugger, call it like this:

```
GetManyBytes(0x40138E, 10, True)
```

Comment: Ok, I tried to write `Dword(0x80456ef)` in the IDC and it worked. Thanks a lot ! But, does someone knows where we can find the complete language usable in the IDC ? Is it matching exactly the idapython language ? Or, is it more ?

Comment: Strangely, the last command that you gave is not working on my IDA Linux because of the "True", you need to write: `GetManyBytes(0x804928c, 10, 1)` to get it to work.

Comment: There is documentation in IDAs help file if you search for IDC. Also, idapython contains a wrapper around the IDC functions in idc.py.

Comment: @newgre: I think for completeness the IDC version should be included as well for the one statement where it differs (ignoring semi-colons). +1

Comment: See `idc.idc` for full docs.

Comment: Also, there is an idc.Qword(addr) which can be used to read x64 offsets. Works in IDA 7.2 x64.

Answer (score 3):

You can also position your cursor in one of the code, hex-view, or stack view windows, and press 'g' to bring up the "jump to address" dialog.

Comment: and in hexview you can select the format you want to view your hexdump in.

Comment: I'm a fan of double clicking addresses in the command window. This is an easy way to jump if you use a script to calculate the address.