# IDA pro: jump back to previous instruction

Tags: ida, debugging, c, immunity-debugger

I'm new with IDA pro and currently running with debugger, I have few questions:

1. How can I jump on previous instruction? Undo the latest instruction ?
2. Is it possible in IDA to examine memory of an executable ? Like it is in Immunity Debugger? Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6weo6.jpg) and examine each segment briefly like it is in Immunity Debugger ?

Comment: check those: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1909/how-to-display-memory-zones-content-on-ida-pro or https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11869/how-to-change-address-in-the-hex-view-in-ida-debugger or https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12087/how-to-display-dump-data-in-ida-debugger

Comment: To jump back to a previous instruction in the disassembly view, just press `ESC`

Answer (score 1):

As for the first point, in order to go back to instruction that was already executed (under the debugger), one needs to use a feature called reverse debugging (or Time Travel Debugging). As far as I know IDA's debugger doesn't have this.

Some other tools that you could use to do a reverse debugging:

- [radare2](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/debugger/revdebug.html)
- [WinDbg Preview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview)
- [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/reversible.html)

Answer (score 0):

Debugging a program means executing its instruction on your CPU, "undoing" the last instruction is usually not possible with a standard debugger.

But you can debug your program in a virtual machine, take memory snapshots at given points while debugging, and restore those snapshots.